# Continuation in Scheme

Tags: scheme, continuations

I think I got what a continuations is (in general), but I can't understand how it is used in Scheme.

Consider this example (from wikipedia [call/cc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call-with-current-continuation))

```
(define (f return)
  (return 2)
  3)
(display (call/cc f)) ;=> 2
```

I cannot understand why:

- the continuation is implicit?right?
- How is the continuation in this case?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The continuation is the "rest of the computation" that remains to be executed. In your particular example, you could think of this as being `(display [])` where `[]` is a hole to be plugged with a value. That is, at the point that `call/cc` is invoked, what remains to be done is the call to display.

What `call/cc` does is take this continuation and puts it in a special value that can be applied like a function. It passes this value to its argument (here `f`). In `f`, the continuation is bound to `return`. So `(return 2)` will basically plug `2` into the continuation, i.e., `(display 2)`.

I don't think this example is actually very helpful, so I think you should read [PLAI](http://www.cs.brown.edu/~sk/Publications/Books/ProgLangs/) if you're interested in learning more about continuations (see Part VII). Another good source is [these lecture notes](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~williams/cs491/appcont.pdf) by Dan Friedman.

Comment: Also, for when you get to putting code into continuation passing style. Here are the lecture notes that are posted online for Professor Friedman's Programming Languages course. https://www.cs.indiana.edu/cgi-pub/c311/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=cps-notes.scm